# How to install and launch Metaio app on Google Glass?

Tags: android, eclipse, crash, google-glass, metaio

I used Eclipse to install Metaio SDK on google glass. In the beginning, the console area show like this

http://ppt.cc/HVfq

I think this means that I successfully complete the installation part, then I try to add voice trigger in order to let the Glass run this app. This is how it looks in my Google Glass.

http://ppt.cc/Szys

But every time I tried to launch it, it had no response. I have no idea what's going on. Did I make some mistakes? Or should I upload my xml file to see if there is anything wrong?

I saw that some people had already launch their app successfully on Google Glass. I was wondering if someone can show me how to do this step by step. Because I'm new to these things. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to Glass and/or Android in general, I strongly advise that you start by building and running the GDK samples that we provided:

> https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/quick-start

While the quick start guide uses the API Demos sample, feel free to use a more real-life example such as the Compass, Stopwatch or Timer samples that are available on our GitHub repository:

> https://github.com/googleglass